# Install namespace packages using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to install two packages (see below) into the same namespace which is `calculator`. I installed each package using `pip install -e .` from the top level of each project. Then I tried to use `import calculator` and `from calculator.adder import add` but the module cannot be found when I import it. I tried using [an approach](https://realpython.com/python-namespace-package/#what-does-a-namespace-package-look-like) discussed on the Real Python website but it doesn't seem to work. How do I install these packages so they reside in the `calculator` namespace so I can do things like `from calculator.adder import add`?

### Package 1

This is the structure of the `adder` package.

```
calculator-add/
├── README.md
├── examples/
│   └── ex_addition.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── src/
    └── calculator/
        └── adder/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── add.py
```

Contents of the `pyproject.toml` is shown below.

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "adder"
version = "0.1"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["calculator"]
namespaces = true
```

Contents of the `src/calculator/adder/__init__.py` is shown below.

```py
from .add import add

__all__ = ['add']
```

### Package 2

This is the structure of the `divider` package.

```
calculator-divide/
├── README.md
├── examples/
│   └── ex_division.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── src/
    └── calculator/
        └── divider/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── divide.py
```

Contents of the `pyproject.toml` is shown below.

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "divider"
version = "0.2"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["calculator"]
namespaces = true
```

Contents of the `src/calculator/divider/__init__.py` is shown below.

```py
from .divide import divide

__all__ = ['divide']
```

Comment: first Remove the `__init__.py` file from the calculator directories in both packages. then modify `pyproject.toml` files of the adder & divider to specify that calculator is a namespace. then you can import them `from calculator.adder import add
from calculator.divider import divide`.

Comment: @Obaskly How do I specify that calculator is a namespace in the pyproject.toml files?

Comment: @Obaskly Also, [this page](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) says `__init__.py` should not be in the top level of the namespace which is what I have done. There can be an `__init__.py` in the sub package.

Comment: The question does not seem to say what the issue is. Is there an error message? Which commands did you run? Did you check that the projects are installed with the correct Python interpreter? Did you check that the namespace packages and the Python files are installed correcty (in `site-packages`)? -- It should be `where = ["src"]`, although I assume it is the default value, so you could probably remove this line entirely, but for sure `where = ["."]` is incorrect from my point of view.

Comment: It should be `where = ["src"]`, although I assume it is the default value, so you could probably remove this line entirely, but for sure `where = ["."]` is incorrect from my point of view. I would also remove the `include` line, it does not seem necessary. And finally `namespaces = true` seems to be the default as well. All in all, I think I would remove the whole `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]` section in both projects. -- Once you have a good `src` layout, *setuptools* should be able to figure out everything automatically.

Comment: @sinoroc Ok, I'll try this and see if it works. Please submit an answer instead of comments.

Comment: I write in the comments because I did not try it, and I am not sure it will solve your issue. If it does solve your issue, feel free to write the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the include statement under the tool.setuptools.packages.find section. It should either be removed or a wildcard should be added so setup tools can interpret it as a namespace. As is, it's directing setuptools to look for the "calculator" module instead.

Additionally, as sinoroc pointed out in your question's comments, both your namespaces and include statements are already the defaults. Namespaces can be outright removed, but the where statement should be changed to "src". Keeping it as the default '.' should work, but you would then run the risk of unintentionally packaging other files into your distribution (ie your readme and examples) if left in the root directory. Plus, it seems to be what your file structure was setup for anyway.

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["calculator.*"]
```

The [setuptools docs page](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout) was actually really helpful when I was banging my head against the same problem and the first block of the [namespace packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) on PyPA was what finally made it all click.

Additionally, if you're attempting to also have a bundled version of the entire namespace as single distribution as I was, the solution is to list all the individual "src" directories in the parent toml's where statement. In this case that would look like:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["calculator-add/src", "calculator-divide/src"]
include = ["calculator.*"]
```

Assuming the file structure:

```
bundle_root/
├── pyproject.toml        # parent toml    
├── calculator-divide/
│   ├── ...
│   └── src/
│       └── calculator/
│           └── divider/
│               └── ...
└── calculator-add/
    ├── ...
    └── src/
       └── calculator/
            └── adder/
                └── ...
```

You can also just restructure the files to avoid duplicate directories, but this way allows you to package both variations without changing anything.

Comment: This is an excellent summary! One question: suppose you have the file structure `bundle_root`. Suppose `calculator-add` requires `calculator-divide`. How should one proceed? Should the pyproject.toml of calculator divide include the calculator-add in its [project].[dependencies]? Or should you instead add it at the setuptools, i.e., somehow include the `where` and `include` at tool.setuptools.packages.find?