# Loosely-coupled Python namespace package

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

Given the namespace package structure as indicated below (example from [Install namespace packages using pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444274/install-namespace-packages-using-pyproject-toml/76616926#76616926)).

```
bundle_root/
├── calculator-divide/
│   ├── ...
│   └── src/
│   │   └── calculator/
│   │       └── divider/
│   │           └── ...
|   ├── pyproject.toml
└── calculator-add/
|   ├── ...
|   └── src/
|   │  └── calculator/
|   │       └── adder/
|   │           └── ...
│   ├── pyproject.toml
```

The namespace package is called `calculator` and contains two subpackages (`calculator-divide` and `calculator-add`). The `pyproject.toml` of each file contains the following block:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["calculator.*"]
```

In this way, it is possible to create several packages (`calculator-add` and `calculator-divide`) and publish them separately.

Now suppose that `calculator-add` REQUIRES `calculator-divide`. How do you (properly) adjust the `pyproject.toml` of `calculator-add`? I imagine the [project] [dependencies] could be used, but I feel like it is better to include it in the `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]` somehow. My question is: how to do this?

My goal is to publish each subpackage individually, so that the subpackages can be installed individually by the user. Yet, I want to ensure that if `calculator-add` is installed, that its dependency `calculator-divide` is also immediately installed.

Comment: I have been able to solve it by simply adding the package `calculator-divide@version` in the project [dependencies]. I do wonder if this is the most elegant way of doing it, as it does require the correct order of releasing versions...